# Infinitely rolling image using CSS

Tags: css

I would like to have a slowly and repeatedly rolling panoramic image - as if we have a slow rolling drum with the picture pasted on its side. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/slscV.jpg for an animation of such a drum. Ideally I would like to do this in HTML/CSS and my attempt at trying is here:

However, the animation does not wrap around nicely as in the drum animation.

```css
      .verticalSpin {
         animation: spinVertical 5s linear infinite;
      }
      .verticalRoll {
         animation: rollVertical 5s linear infinite;
      }
      .verticalRoll:hover, .verticalSpin:hover {
          animation-play-state: paused
      }
      
      @keyframes spinVertical {
         0% {
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
         }

         100% {
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
         }
      }

      @keyframes rollVertical {
         0% {
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-right: -100px;
         }

         100% {
            margin-left: -100px;
            margin-right: 100px;
         }
      }
```

```html
   <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="verticalRoll">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px;"
           alt="home" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />    
      </div>
      <p style="font-family: arial, helvetica, serif; color: blue; border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: lightblue; color: blue;">
         Image Animation.
      </p>
   </div>
```

Would appreciate any help/pointers to make this happen! Many thanks!!